# Uniform integer divider

Tags: algorithm

The problem looks like this, 
You have to draw N px width line as a M uniform dashes.

If for example N=13 and M=5 you our dash will have 2 px width and we will have 3 px error.

We can do better, we can draw dashes with following widths: 3, 3, 3, 2, 2 .
But we can do even better the dashes can have following widths: 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 .

If I have a list a = ( 3, 3, 3, 2, 2 ) how can I find such list that the distance 'D' between all pairs in the list will be maximum?

In this example D(a) = 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 1.
For list b = ( 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 ), D(b) = 1+1+1+1 = 4.

What is the fastest/simplest method?

Comment: Is this [homework]? What have you got so far? Also can you add some more information as I don't fully understand why 3-2-3-2-3 is better than 3-3-3-2-2. Why do we want to maximise D()?

Comment: We want to maximise D() because we want to draw elements that would look like equal and all will have chosen size. For example imagine drawing arbitrary sized chessboard.

Comment: Is there no space between the dashes?

Comment: This can be achieved in O(M) time, assuming mathematical operations are O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method I know of ? Using floating point numbers...

In Python:

```
def pace(D,M): return [round(float(D) / M * i) for i in range(1,M+1)]
```

I have already seen this somewhere here I think.

Comment: Beautiful, this is good and simple answer. The only think is that this not give us the answer how to find solution to the more general problem - given a set of integers, find such permutation that maximizes D, but as I said, this is great solution to my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something inspired by [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) should do the trick. Believe me, you don't want to maximize D over all permutations of your set. This problem is overly complex (complexity is O(n!), so unless n is very small, this won't work)

Comment: Maybe this is a good direction. I didn't thought about it when I searched for the answer.
Of course I didn't want to maximize the function of the objective! I just wanted to express the problem in an formal way.